# dyn_recfg c++: compiling but no items in rqt_reconfigure

Tags: ros, function, parameter, rqt, dynamic-reconfigure

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI, I try to get the dynamic reconfigure to run in c++.
My Project is compiling without problems, but the variables do not appear in rqt?
I have a class based structure like following:

//Class Instance: class_instance.h

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "project_name/ManipulatorConfig.h"
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

class ClassInstance{
    void ClassInstance::subReconfigureCallback(project_name::ProjectConfig &config, uint32_t level) {
      ROS_INFO("Reconfigure Request: %f", config.joint1_angle);
      ROS_INFO("Reconfigure Request: %f", config.joint2_angle);
      ROS_INFO("Reconfigure Request: %f", config.joint3_angle);
   }
   ClassInstance(){
     dynamic_reconfigure::Server<project_name::ProjectConfig> server;
     dynamic_reconfigure::Server<project_name::ProjectConfig>::CallbackType f;
     f = boost::bind(&ClassInstance::subReconfigureCallback, this, _1, _2);
     server.setCallback(f);
   }
}
```

//Main: main.cpp

```
#include "ros/ros.h"
#include "class_instance.h" 
int main(int argc, char **argv){
    ros::init(argc, argv, "project_name_node");
    ClassInstance class_instance;
    ros::spin();    
    return 0; 
}
```

//ProjectConfig.cfg

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
PACKAGE = "project_name"
from dynamic_reconfigure.parameter_generator_catkin import *
gen = ParameterGenerator()
gen.add("var1", double_t, 0, "A double parameter",    0, 0.0,  2.0)
gen.add("var2", double_t, 0, "A double parameter",    0, 0.0,  2.0)
gen.add("var3", double_t, 0, "A double parameter",    0, 0.0,  2.0)
exit(gen.generate(PACKAGE, "project_name", "Project"))
```

The CMAKELISTS and PACKAGE are created according to the dynamix reconfigure tutorial.
Do you have any idea?
Thanks a lot!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256328/dyn_recfg-c++:-compiling-but-no-items-in-rqt_reconfigure/) by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 170 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> class ClassInstance{
> ```

```
   ...
   ClassInstance(){
     dynamic_reconfigure::Server<project_name::ProjectConfig> server;
     dynamic_reconfigure::Server<project_name::ProjectConfig>::CallbackType f;
     f = boost::bind(&ClassInstance::subReconfigureCallback, this, _1, _2);
     server.setCallback(f);
   }
}
```

This is really more a C++ issue than something to do with ROS, but: you're `server` variable is not a member of your class, but just an instance that has a scope that is local to the `ClassInstance` constructor.

On other words: `server` will only exist for the short time that the c'tor is executed, after which it will be destroyed.

Make `server` a member variable and then initialise it in your c'tor, that should resolve your issue.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JanOr](https://answers.ros.org/users/21288/janor/) on 2017-03-07**:
Wow that was fast.
You are absolutely right.
It works now.
Thanks a lot!